# Random Forest in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest

So I am trying to classify certain text documents into three classes.

I wrote the following code for Cross validation in spark

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
# Define a grid of hyperparameters to test:
#  - maxDepth: max depth of each decision tree in the GBT ensemble
#  - maxIter: iterations, i.e., number of trees in each GBT ensemble
# In this example notebook, we keep these values small.  In practice, to get the highest accuracy, you would likely want to try deeper trees (10 or higher) and more trees in the ensemble (>100).

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
  .addGrid(jpsa.rf.maxDepth, [2,4,10])\
  .addGrid(jpsa.rf.numTrees, [100, 250, 600,800,1000])\
  .build()

# We define an evaluation metric.  This tells CrossValidator how well we are doing by comparing the true labels with predictions.
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1", labelCol=jpsa.rf.getLabelCol(), predictionCol=jpsa.rf.getPredictionCol())
# Declare the CrossValidator, which runs model tuning for us.
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,numFolds=5)

cvModel=cv.fit(jpsa.jpsa_train)

evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(jpsa.jpsa_train))
```

I dont have much data. 115 total observation(documents with labels). I break them into 80:35 training and test. On the training I use 5 fold cross validation using the above code.

The evaluator above gave me the following on whole training data.

```
evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(jpsa.jpsa_train))
0.9021290600237969
```

I am using f1 here since I am not able to find aucROC for MulticlassEvaluator in Spark as the option for evaluator. It does have it for Binary. I know AUC is for binary class, but then we can get a combined or average AUC for multi class by plotting various binary classes and getting their AUC. Sri-kit learn does the same for Multi class AUC.

However, when I use the evaluator on test data, my f1 score is miserable.

```
evaluator.evaluate(cvModel.transform(jpsa.jpsa_test))
0.5830903790087463
```

This indicates it's overfitting. Also if I don't use 1000 and 800 trees in the hyparameter search space and just keep it to 600 and 800, my test accuracy is 69%. So that means more trees are leading to overfitting? Which is strange as that is contrary to what and how Random Forests work. More tress reduce variance and lead to less overfitting (in fact ppl even suggest sometimes random forests don't overfit though I disagree that with very less data and complex forest it can).

Is that what is happening here? Less data and more no. of trees leading to overfitting?

Also how do I get a measure of cross validation accuracy? Currently evaluator is on training data. I don't want that as a measure to choose the algo. I want the validation data. Is it possible to get this OOB estimate internally from this CV estimator?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter selection is an important aspect in developing machine learning models. To do this, there are multiple ways. One of them would be this one. Use 50% data (stratified) for parameter selection. Divide this data into 10 folds. Now perform 10-fold cross validation along with grid search with the tuning parameters. Usually the parameters to tune in a random forest are the number of trees and the depth of each tree (There are other parameters as well such as the number of features to select for each split, but generally the default parameter works well).

Also, it is true that higher number of trees can reduce variance, but it is too much high it can increase bias. There is trade-off. Create a grid with number of trees varying from 10 to 100 with step of 10, 50 or 100.

Comment: I hope you checked my code before answering this?. I have done all of that and my question is why that is happening

Comment: @Baktaawar If you go through the answer, I have mentioned that as the number of trees increase, variance may decrease but bias will increase. In your case that is what is happening.

Comment: If the no. of trees increase and as per you bias increases then it would lead to underfitting and not overfitting. More bias leads to underfitting. High variance leads to overfitting. In my case it appears I am seeing overfitting and not underfitting so your answer unfortunately speaks contrary which is not correct in my opinion

Comment: Hope somebody can help you with better answer! Good Luck